# How to set variable from stored procedure in query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get data from sp inside a query and set it to a variable.
following is my query

```
WHILE ( ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS [COUNT]
          FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.AdditionalRefNumberPO
                 FROM dbo.tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder
                 WHERE tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.AdditionalRefNumberPO IS NOT NULL
                 ORDER BY tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.PROId DESC
               ) AS T122
        ) > 0 )
    DECLARE @rr VARCHAR(9)= ( SELECT TOP 1 tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.AdditionalRefNumberPO
                              FROM dbo.tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder
                              WHERE tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.AdditionalRefNumberPO IS NOT NULL
                              ORDER BY tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder.PROId DESC
                            );
          SET @rr= EXEC dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO @rr
```

but i am getting 
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.**

on

```
 SET @rr= EXEC dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO @rr
```

i am using sql server 2014
please help :)

Comment: `EXEC dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO @rr OUTPUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put data from SP into variable - you need to use [OUTPUT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO
    ...
    @rr VARCHAR(9) OUTPUT
AS
...
```

Then you can use it like:

```
DECLARE @rr VARCHAR(9);

EXECUTE dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO ... @rr = @rr OUTPUT

SELECT @rr
```

In last select you will get value that was get from SP execution.

The main question is - You are using WHILE loop, so you got some `@rr`, then pass it to SP and try to write output from SP in that variable, but on next run you will get another `@rr` from your query. Maybe you need to use another variable? What is the purpose of this query?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't need to use `COUNT()` in your `IF` condition.  Just use `EXISTS`.

Second, you need `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
WHILE (. . . )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rr VARCHAR(MAX)= (SELECT TOP 1 o.AdditionalRefNumberPO
                               FROM dbo.tbl_PurchaseRequisitionOrOrder o
                               WHERE o.AdditionalRefNumberPO IS NOT NULL
                               ORDER BY o.PROId DESC);
     EXEC dbo.GetAddiRefNumberPO @rr ;
END;
```

Notes:

- Stored procedures return integers, not strings.  So, if you want the return value, you need to an integer variable, not a string one.  But you are not using the retval, so I removed it.
- Your error was cause because the `WHILE` was only declaring the variable `@rr`.  The `EXEC` was the next statement after the `WHILE` loop.
- I recommend that you *always* use `BEGIN`/`END` for any control statements, such as `WHILE` and `IF`.  Now you know why.
- Table aliases make queries easier to write and to read.